# Rails what is this variable(an object, a hash, an array, etc) and how can I access it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a rails application and I'm trying to access this variable and I keep getting undefined method errors, etc.

In my controller, I am doing:

```
@application = Application.find(params[:id])
@curr_app_id = @application.application_field.last(1)
puts @curr_app_id
```

and it prints out

```
#<ApplicationField:0x56678b8>
```

What type of variable is this, and how can i access it's ID?

Comment: Might help to know what the types of the other variables are. Is `@application` a model? If not, what is it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `puts @curr_app_id.inspect` please? Also, can you try without the (1) argument for the `last` statement?

Comment: Good point. question is updated.

Comment: in my IRB: `User.last(1).class #=> Array` and `User.last.class #=> User`. I thing this argument to the `last` method is making trouble here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some investigation in my IRB console ...

```
1.9.3p0 :018 > puts User.last(1).class # => Array
1.9.3p0 :019 > puts User.last.class    # => User
1.9.3p0 :018 > puts User.last(1) # => #<User:0x00000006f36280>
1.9.3p0 :019 > puts User.last    # => #<User:0x00000006f36280>
```

**Same output, different classes**!

Giving an integer to the `last` method (even if you give 1) results in a Array: [Class Array (Ruby 1.9.3) here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last).

```
1.9.3p0 :028 > puts User.last(1).id
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x00000006f2d8d8>
```

You should use last without parameter:

```
@application = Application.find(params[:id])
@curr_app_id = @application.application_field.last
# then you should be able to use the object's methods:
puts @curr_app_id.id
```

Answer (score 1):

`@application.application_field.last` is returning an `ApplicationField` object.  Passing an integer to `#last` will return the number of objects in an array.

So, `@application.application_field.last(2)` will return the last two application_field objects associated with `@application` in an array.

`@application.application_field.last` should give you the `ApplicationField` object.  calling `#id` on it, `@application.application_field.last.id`, should return the id presuming that it is an ActiveRecord model (or `respond_to?(:id)` some other way).